# IE Mobile CSS and Images Don't Load on Redirect

Tags: html, css, image, mobile

I am using a Nokia 610 to test IE mobile.

We have a button that redirects the user to another page served over HTTPs. When the user gets redirect to the page the CSS and images aren't loaded.

However if you refresh the page or go to the page directly the CSS and images are loaded. Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: If desktop IE wasn't bad enough... Why are you doing this to yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying full paths for the images and using "http"? IE might not be loading them due to being insecure content over https.